# How to produce multiple similar Grafana dashboards for kube-prometheus-stack? What does makes the collision that I see only one from the bunch of them

Tags: kubernetes-helm, grafana, grafana-templating, kube-prometheus-stack, grafana-dashboard

I have updated the standard dashboard yaml to those who iterates over the configuration:

```
{{- /*
    Generated from 'apiserver' from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/master/manifests/grafana-dashboardDefinitions.yaml
    Do not change in-place! In order to change this file first read following link:
      https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/kube-prometheus-stack/hack
    */ -}}
  {{- $kubeTargetVersion := default .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion .Values.kubeTargetVersionOverride }}
  {{- if $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.alerting }}
  {{- if and (semverCompare ">=1.14.0-0" $kubeTargetVersion) (semverCompare "<9.9.9-9" $kubeTargetVersion) .Values.grafana.enabled .Values.grafana.defaultDashboardsEnabled .Values.kubeApiServer.enabled }}
  {{ $c := 0 | int }}
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.alerting }}
  {{ $c = add1 $c }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: {{ $.Release.Namespace }}
  name: {{ printf "%s-%s" (include "kube-prometheus-stack.fullname" $) "alerting" | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" }}-{{ $key }}
  annotations:
  {{ toYaml $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.annotations | indent 4 }}
  labels:
  {{- if $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.label }}
    {{ $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.label }}: "{{ $c }}"
    {{- end }}
    app: {{ template "kube-prometheus-stack.name" $ }}-grafana
  {{ include "kube-prometheus-stack.labels" $ | indent 4 }}
data:
  alerting{{ $key }}.json: |-
{
  "annotations": {
    "list": [
      {
        "builtIn": 1,
        "datasource": "-- Grafana --",
        "enable": true,
        "hide": true,
        "iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
        "name": "Annotations & Alerts",
        "type": "dashboard"
      }
    ]
  },
  "description": "Custom {{ $key }} alerting setup",
  "editable": true,
  "gnetId": 11542{{ $c }},
  "id": 900{{ $c }},
  "graphTooltip": 0,
  "links": [],
  "panels": [

...
],
      "timezone": "",
      "title": "{{ $.Values.grafana.sidecar.dashboards.env }} Custom {{ $key }} Alerting setup",
      "uid": "alerting{{ $key }}",
      "version": 1
    }
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
```

and then it goes the dashboard part, yet parametrized with values from the yaml like that:

```
  sidecar:
    dashboards:
      enabled: true
      label: grafana_dashboard
      env: Dev
      ## Annotations for Grafana dashboard configmaps
      ##
      annotations: {}
      multicluster: false
      alerting:
        trains:
          ourdashboardstuff: ourvalues
        ships:
          ourdashboardstuff: ourvalues
```

As the result, 2 different `ConfigMap`s are produced by helm upgrade. I can even see them with `--dry-run`. So, my expectation that I'll see 2 different dashbords like `Dev Custom ships Alerting setup` and `Dev Custom trains Alerting setup`, but I see an only one like grafana ignores 2 `ConfigMap`s with dashboard details at one helm output.

All keys are definitely not collide to each others, what makes Grafana to ignore the second dashboard config produced by the helm output?